# sorting strings in an array alphabetically

Tags: arrays, string, sorting

I came up with this code to try and sort out an array of strings (I don't want to use ints or imports as I'm trying to understand iteration loops), but it only rearranges the first two strings. Can anyone point out my mistakes?

```
public class Alpha8 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String[] Names = {"O","B","K","S","D","M","N","A"};

       String temp = null;

       for(int i=0;i<Names.length;i++){
           for(int j = i+1;j<Names.length;j++) {        
               if(Names[j].compareTo(Names[i])<0)
                   temp = Names[i];
                   Names[i] = Names[j];
                   Names[j] = temp;

                   for( i = 0;i<Names.length;i++){        
                        System.out.println(Names[i]);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: write  for( i = 0;i<Names.length;i++)
  {System.out.println(Names[i]);
  }  outside the loop

Comment: First I would suggest fixing up the formatting in the code. The indenting/spacing seems entirely random.

Comment: Your if statement `if(Names[j].compareTo(Names[i])<0)` doesn't enclose its body in `{...}` so only the first statement is the body.  The code does this if statement: `if(Names[j].compareTo(Names[i])<0) temp = Names[i];` and then the next two lines are ALWAYS executed: `Names[i] = Names[j]; Names[j] = temp;`  You should have written: `if(Names[j].compareTo(Names[i])<0) { temp = Names[i]; Names[i] = Names[j];  Names[j] = temp; }`

Comment: Thanks Jerry Jeremiah, your answer was spot on, I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

You have made two mistakes:

1. You are printing the array inside your 'swap' code. You should only print the array once the sorting is complete.
2. You only iterate through the array once. For a bubble sort (which is what you are implementing) you need to keep iterating through until no swaps occur.

The method should look something like:

```
boolean hasSwapped;
do {
    hasSwapped = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < names.size(); i++) {
        if (names[i-1].compareTo(names[i]) > 0) {
            swap(names[i-1], names[i]);
            hasSwapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (hasSwapped);
```